# Setting AppPool Idle Timeout with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis-6, application-pool

How do you set an IIS6 app pool's idle timeout with powershell? All I am seeing from my searches is how to set the app pool recycle time which isn't quite the same.

This is what is turning up, but I don't think it's what I am looking for:

```
$destinationPool.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but try this:

```
$ApplicationPool = Get-WmiObject -Class IISApplicationPoolSetting -Namespace "root/microsoftiisv2" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'W3SVC/APPPOOLS/DefaultAppPool'}
$ApplicationPool.IdleTimeout=0
$ApplicationPool.Put()
```

Comment: Using the namespace "rootmicrosoftiisv2" threw an invalid namespace exception for me so I swapped that with "root\MicrosoftIISv2" and it executed without any exceptions; however the idle time was not changed.

Comment: Okay it works now, there was a typo in my test code which passed the incorrect app name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using DSC (Desired State Configuration)

```
cAppPool $application.AppPool.Name 
{ 
    Name                    = $application.AppPool.Name                 
    AutoStart               = $application.AppPool.AutoStart            
    StartMode               = $application.AppPool.StartMode            
    ManagedRuntimeVersion   = $application.AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion
    ManagedPipelineMode     = $application.AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode  
    IdentityType            = $application.AppPool.IdentityType  
    LoadUserProfile         = $application.AppPool.LoadUserProfile
    Ensure                  = "Present" 
    idleTimeout             = "00:00:00"
}
```

The fact that `idleTimeout` was a `string` and not an `int` type tripped me up for a while. Trying to use `"0"` silently leaves it at the default of 20mins

(See [cAppPool on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/cWebAdministration/blob/master/DSCResources/PSHOrg_cAppPool/PSHOrg_cAppPool.psm1))